# mvn.bat pom.xml clean install. Error: Could not find or load main class install

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

I have my tests running on Slave machine and is connected to master. Configured a job in Jenkins which runs on slave machine. All environment variable is set on master as well on slave. I am trying to invoke a target of pom to execute tesng xml.

## Error:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on EnterpriseAdaptersNightlySlave in workspace C:\Jenkins\workspace\NetAppAdapterTests
[NetAppAdapterTests] $ C:\apache-maven-3.1.1-bin\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\mvn.bat -f depot\stats-service\main\QA\pom.xml clean install
Error: Could not find or load main class install
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
```

Comment: I am using code in pom:

Comment: <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<suiteXmlFiles>
<suiteXmlFile>src\testnetappAdapterTestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
<properties>
<property>
<name>listener</name>
<value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
</property>
</properties>
<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
<systemProperties><property>
<name>org.uncommons.reportng.title</name>
<value>${com.vmware.vcopsqa.tests.reports.title}</value>
</property></systemProperties></configuration></plugin>

Comment: command C:\apache-maven-3.1.1-bin\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\mvn.bat -f depot\stats-service\main\QA\pom.xml is running good at slave machine.

Comment: You said that the command runs fine on slave machine. Did you try it under the same user that the slave is running under?

Comment: I tried running this command as an Administrator user, and all environment variables are set under system variable. And I am running Jenkins connector under administrator user only.

Answer (score 0):

Does slave Jenkins job have the M2_HOME environment variable defined properly (I mean, it should point to the same Maven instance that is running during job execution)? Keep an eye on this, may be there is some kind of mismatch presents.

Comment: Actually I had a problem like this before(ERROR: A Maven installation needs to be available for this project to be built.Either your server has no Maven installations defined, or the requested Maven version does not exist). I added one more MAVEN_HOME path which points to the maven home directory of Slave Jenkins also I did this change for JAVA_HOME(I did this changes under Jenkins>Configuration tab). After that I got that issue resolved.  Moreover how can I get to know there is any mismatch in maven instances?

Comment: You have Maven running from `C:\apache-maven-3.1.1-bin\apache-maven-3.1.1 folder`
Thus, you should ensure that M2_HOME environment variable within your Jenkins job should point to the same location. You may fetch your environment by running "help:system" Maven goal before building the project.